# Import ods with newline in cells

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, openoffice-calc

I have an ods spreadsheet (managed with OpenOffice). Several cells contain multiple lines. The data table contents are used for display on a website.
When I import the file with phpmyadmin, these cells are truncated at the first newline character.
In the ods file, the newline character is char(10). In my case this has to be replaced with the string `<br/>`,the HTML newline tag. Writing a php program that does the replacement makes no sense since the newline character is already cut after import. For the moment I run a pc program that patches the char(10) with the '|' character in the ods file. After import, I replace the '|' with `<br/>` using php. Terrible! Is there a way to prevent the import by phpmyadmin to truncate on char(10)?
Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. My solution is not the perfect one but did the job for me.

What I did was, I replaced new line character in ODS so I can replace it back in PHP.
Open ODS file, open search&replace box then search \n and replace it some unique char where u can locate in PHP.

in my case I did something like *-EOL-*
in my php script replaced *-EOL-* with

I know it's not shortcut but a solution...

Hope it works for u as well

Comment: I tried your solution. However, OpenOffice does not find anything when I put \n in the search field. I suppose the program was looking for \n literally in the spreadsheet. Thanks, Chris.